# AttributeError implementing Bicycle Routing function in Herepy

Tags: python, here-api, herepy

While the link [here](https://herepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/herepy.html) shows that the Herepy library supports Here-API's bicycle routing, I cannot make it work (while car routing works great).

When running:

```
import herepy

#https://herepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/herepy.html

lat1,lng1 = 45.575402, -73.209555
lat2,lng2 = 45.595625, -73.619487

routingApi = herepy.RoutingApi('a key', 'another key')
byCar = routingApi.car_route([lat1,lng1],[lat2,lng2],[herepy.RouteMode.car, herepy.RouteMode.fastest])
byBike = routingApi.bicycle_route([lat1,lng1],[lat2,lng2])
```

I get :

> AttributeError: 'RoutingApi' object has no attribute 'bicycle_route'

Is the bicycle_route() function not implemented properly, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? An empty result? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this function [was just added recently](https://github.com/abdullahselek/HerePy/commit/7c913541961dfebf6673b5e0ba1456e0d382ef10), try installing the latest version from source, i.e.:

1. Clone [the repo](https://github.com/abdullahselek/HerePy)
2. Run `python setup.py install`